# Update Component after post new item to the Database sveltekit

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

I want to update the todo after adding a new todo which gets stored into the backend and updates the previously displayed component with the new one which has a new todo.

**Here is my TodoStore.js file which fetches data and sends todos to the server**

```
let todoStore = writable([]);

const fetchTodos = async () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/todos')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => todoStore.set(data));
};

async function addTodo(todoBody) {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/todos', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: todoBody
            })
        });
        const data = res.json();
        fetchTodos();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

const deleteTodo = async (id) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/todos/${id}`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'DELETE'
    });
    const msg = res.json();
    console.log(msg);
};

fetchTodos();

export { todoStore, fetchTodos, addTodo, deleteTodo };
```

**And Here is the TodoForm.svelte file which interacts with the store in order to add a todo**

```
    import { addTodo, todoStore } from '../stores/TodoStore';
    let todoBody = '';
</script>

<form class="add-form">
    <input type="text" bind:value={todoBody} />
    <button
        class="btn-blue"
        on:click|preventDefault={() => {
            addTodo(todoBody);
        }}>Add Todo</button
    >
</form>
```

**I don't know whether it's related but here is my Todos.svelte and TodoItem.svelte**
***Todos.svelte***

```
    import TodoItem from './TodoItem.svelte';
    export let todos;
</script>

<div class="todo-wrapper">
    {#each todos as todo}
        <TodoItem title={todo.title} completed={todo.completed} id={todo._id} />
    {/each}
</div>
```

***TodoItem.svelte***

```
    export let title;
    export let completed;
    export let id;
    let deleted = false;
    import { deleteTodo } from '../stores/TodoStore';
</script>

<div class="todo-item {deleted == true ? 'nodisplay' : ''}">
    {#if completed == true || completed == 'true'}
        <h2 class="line-through">{title}</h2>
    {:else}
        <h2>{title}</h2>
    {/if}
    <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={completed} />
    <i
        class="fa-solid fa-trash"
        on:click={() => {
            deleteTodo(id);
            deleted = true;
        }}
    />
</div>
```

Please help me if you have a solution

Comment: can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: You are somehow missing a step, how does `Todos.svelte` know about the `todoStore` ?

Comment: the todoStore is passed into Todos.svelte as a prop